# Unpin Internet Explorer from the Taskbar in Windows 10 Build 20H2 using PowerShell

Tags: windows, build, taskbar

Has anyone found a working solution to unpin Internet Explorer (and other apps) from the Taskbar in Win 10 B20H2 / 21H2?

I tryed ALOT of the solutions in google top searches, but none seems to work with Win10 B20H2.

Export and import of the layout xml is not an option.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/214599/unpin-icons-from-taskbar-in-windows-10-20h2.html

They suggest this script, but for me it doesn't work - it executes and returns no errors, but doesn't unpin the shortcut:

```
$appname = "Microsoft Store"
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from taskbar'} | %{$_.DoIt(); $exec = $true}
```

Answer (score 3):

The example you posted have some typos.
You can try the following:

1. Execute the following command and find the name of the applications you want to unpin

```bash
  (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | 
  Sort-Object Name | Select-Object Name
```

2. If you have a display language other than English, do the following command to find your **Unpin from taskbar** verb

```bash
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | 
Select-Object -First 1 ).Verbs() | Select-Object Name
```

3. Create an array with the apps you want to remove, and unpin it

   - If you did step 2, replace the `$Action` variable with the verb you found (without any symbols like `&`).

```bash
$appnames = @("App1", "App2", "App3")
$Action = "Unpin from taskbar"
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | 
  Where-Object { $appnames -contains $_.Name }).Verbs() | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name.replace('&','') -match $Action} | 
  ForEach-Object {$_.DoIt()}
```

Comment: This works fine on Windows Server 2019 as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm flabberghasted that this works in pssession. Huzzah! ty

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the script. It took us a while before we figure out that it work only for English Windows language version.

***You have to translate "Unpin from taskbar" to your Windows language version.***

For a Polish Windows edition, the proper script to unpin Internet Explorer is as follows:

```
$appnames = @("Internet Explorer")
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | 
 Where-Object { $appnames -contains $_.Name }).Verbs() |
 Where-Object {$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Odepnij od paska'} |   ForEach-Object {$_.DoIt()}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33885536)

Comment: Nice! I updated my answer with an additional step to be dynamic with any language